# PHP Display Content 90% Of The Time

Tags: php, random, logic

Let's say that I have 2 images, an image of dogs and an image of cats.

When I load my web page I want to show the image of the dogs 90% of the time and the image of the cats 10% of the time.

An easy way I thought might be to select a random number between 1 and 10, and every time the number '1' is selected I show the image of the cats and any other numbers shows the picture of the dogs.

```
$number = rand(1, 10);
```

However, after reading into this method just a little, it seems as though some numbers might have more bias of being selected than others.

What are your thoughts? Is **rand** or **mt_rand** good enough? Or are their other, maybe better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another viable option would be to use the time the page was loaded.

```
<?
if (time() % 10) { // true whenever time doesn't end with a 0
    woof();
} else {
    meow();
}
?>
```

Time, as far as I know, isn't biased :)

Comment: Nice, however 90% and 10% were just example figures. That's my fault for not explaining fully. But thanks, that could come in handy one day.

Comment: My example could be read as "9 times out of 10, do this", and changing the number to, say, 5, would change it to "4 times out of 5". The number is there to be tinkered with.

Comment: Also, using `if (time() % 10 < 5) {` would make if "5 times out of 10". The numbers aren't important here, the idea of using `time()` is.

Comment: Ah yes I see, this is what I am looking for. I can't see in any way how this would be bias - perfect!